Ferrite bead for GPIO
I am driving 24 LEDs with the LED matrix circuit as shown in the figure. There are base resistors for PNP transistors and series resistors for each LED. I want to use ferrite beads (BLM15PX221SN1D) in series with LED resistors to protect MCU pins from EMC/transients etc.. Would the ferrite beads here work? Or will these beads cause other problems? What are your recommendations?


Hello and welcome ... please could you edit in a different image because this one isn't really readable?

i have edited the image.

In passing I notice you have a quite a number of "surprise blobs" (eg at R3-LED26.K) where you might possibly have two wires; these sometimes are shorting components out and are always worth removing.  Also D12.E (very peculiar name for a transistor!)

What makes you concerned about EMC here?  Are there long wires or external connections?  Separately - make sure the MCU can safely sink the current from all those LEDs.

Where are the LEDs placed/arranged that there is an EMC immunity concern about them? Please show PCB layout, and proposed assembly drawings (PCB, enclosure, connectors (general connections and functions), wiring/harness, etc.). What test levels are you concerned about?

I ran the sample circuit, and did not see any problems. But, is it possible that driving the LEDs in this way will damage the processor? such as the flash memory getting corrupted or suddenly stopping normal operation. What I meant by EMC  was whether it would cause similar errors, and are these beads useful to avoid encountering these errors? Or, would it make more sense to put TVS diodes on the gpio pins?

Yes the processor can be damaged by sinking to much current. This processor has a limit of some 20mA per GPIO.

Loading on pins is not an EMC topic per se. EMC concerns the electromagnetic behavior of a circuit, particularly with ambient/radiated EM fields.

According to the Murata Electronics SimSurfing website, the peak resistance of the BLM15PX221SN1D is at ~261 MHz, with a half peak resistance range of 72 MHz to 630 MHz. Are you expecting EMC or transients in that range?

Ferrite beads behave as inductors at MHz frequencies, that can cause undesirable effects.

Generally the ferrite beads would be useless on the LED pins.
They don't block much ESD if you expect someone to touch the LEDs or LED pins. If you want to combat ESD, put ESD protection there. But the resistor will already limit ESD a lot so MCU internal protection may suffice. Another thing is, why do you expect ESD on LEDs, put a casing which protects the PCB from being directly touched.
The MCU pins are outputs so they are quite resilient to EMC.
The MCU pins may output EMC, but any fast signals would be better blocked at lower frequency already than with ferrite beads.
If those were data signals (like SPI clock or data), ferrite beads would cause signal integrity issues by allowing over- and undershoots on each edge, possibly ringing too. A simple resistor would be better and make a cleaner signal with lower bandwidth. In any event, the MCU already has pin drive strength control selectable with software, but strong drive needed for LEDs also makes the signals have fast edges and fast edges are bad for EMI.
Of course the LEDs do not care about such integrity issues.
